# Parsing file via Python

Tags: python

Please help me to parse the file of Nagios config via Python script.
I got the array with hostnames, and from this need to parse file and get their members. How i can do this?

There is my code :

```
import os
hostgroups=os.popen('grep hostgroup_name /var/log/nagios/objects.cache | cut -f3').read().split('\n')
for i in hostgroups[:-1]:
    print i
```

how parse file again or what to do to get members. 
Example see below :

```
define hostgroup {
        hostgroup_name  test
        alias   test
        members server1,server2
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should parse the file with python instead of grep:

For example:

```
with open("/var/log/nagios/objects.cache") as nagiosFile:
    hostgroups = {}
    hostgroup_name = None
    for line in nagiosFile.readlines():
        if "hostgroup_name" in line:
            hostgroup_name = line.split()[-1]
        if "members" in line:
            for members in line.split():
                hostgroups[hostgroup_name] = members.split(",")
    print hostgroups
```

Comment: yeah, this. It's can help. But issue in the next - some hosgroups didn't have any members, so how i know, this code will be crashed, no?

Comment: This code will not crash but the result will be false. This is just an example... You need to adapt it for your specific need.